# Is there a noun for the word "exact" that is like the word "similarity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, is-it-a-word

I am not sure how to word this correctly, but I am looking for a noun for the word "exact" that is basically like the word "similarity". Would the word "exactitude" be what I am looking for?

Here is the sentence as it stands now: "I could see the similarities, and the exactitudes, between our lifestyles."

Is this acceptable, or is there a better noun that I do not know of?

Comment: [Exactness](https://www.lexico.com/definition/exactness)

Comment: Mathematicians use "exactness".

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you for your contribution. I was also thinking of that word, but did not know if it was correct.

Comment: The word doesn't make sense here.

Comment: *Sameness* might work.

Comment: @Xanne: Sameness is not exactness, it is more connected to similarity.  It is not clear from the OP's context if "exactitudes" refers to the fact that each of the lifestyles is exact . We need clarification on this. Does the "exactitude" modify "similarity" or "lifestyles"?